# Using ssindex / svnindex fails : "Unable to resolve directory"

Tags: svn, symstore

I try to index my symbol files with a SVN repository, with the command

svnindex /debug /source=c:\crash /symbols=c:\crash\release

Whatever I try, I always get :

```
ssindex.cmd [STATUS] : Running... this will take some time...
ssindex.cmd [WARN  ] SVN: Unable to resolve directory: Bad file descriptor
ssindex.cmd [INFO  ] : ... indexing c:\Crash\Release\CrashTest.pdb
ssindex.cmd [INFO  ] : ... zero source files found ...
ssindex.cmd [INFO  ] : ... indexing c:\Crash\Release\vc100.pdb
ssindex.cmd [INFO  ] : ... zero source files found ...
```

c:\crash contains a simple MFC demo program that is in a SVN repository on my local drive (d:\Repo_Crash).
I'm installed ActivePerl-5.20.2.2002-MSWin32-x86-64int-299195 and the standalone debug kit of WDK8.1. I set a path to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\srcsrv. SVN version is 1.9.0 (r1692801)

When looking at the file svn.pm, I see that the next part (line 126) always fails:

```
my $hProcess;
if ( ! open($hProcess, "dir $SourceRoot 2>&1 |") ) {
::warn_message("Unable to resolve directory: $!");
return();
}
```

So it gives me that warning message and then returns.

Any idea what is wrong here?

ps: I have been googling like hell, but found nothing relevant

Answer (score 0):

This is just for your information like me.

Look at the PATH variable to see where perl is running.

Only ActiveState's Perl runs `"dir $SourceRoot 2>&1 |"`

Comment: This doesn't really make any sense - can you reword your answer so that it reads better ?